# Phonegap android hdpi icon doesn't change from defualt

Tags: android, cordova, icons, hdpi

I know a lot of questions like this have been asked but nothing seems to fix this: the android hdpi icon won't change (but the rest do) its always the default cordova icon (yes the icons exsist).

in config.xml

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<!-- ldpi --> 
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"  gap:platform="android" width="36" height="36" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" /> 
<!-- mdpi --> 
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" width="48" height="48" /> 
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" /> 
<!-- hdpi --> 
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" width="72" height="72" /> 
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" /> 
<!-- xhdpi --> 
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" width="96" height="96" /> 
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way using hooks, adding a script and putting this in config.xml:

```
<hook type="after_prepare" src="hooks/iconFix.js" />
```

using the script from here: 
http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason two ios icon values were overriding my android icons:

```
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" width="144" />
```

I figured it out by using the command
`cordova prepare android --verbose` and noticing the ios files were being copied into my Android resource directory.